# How to disable the hover event when I hover over the text inside the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in my code, when I hover over the image, the image will become 50% larger and it will display a text over the image, but when I hover over the text, the image will enter the state of mouseout, mouseover, mouseout, mouseover. So it will flicker a lot. How can I disable this hovering event when the mouse is over the text of the image? I tried `event.stopPropagation` in the text but it isn't working.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7C4b/). Try to hover over the image, then try to hover over the text. That's the effect I'm talking about. I want to disable the text hover event. Please help me.

Comment: you have written too much code for this simple thing

Comment: do you want something like yours but less complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution for this,

> I would do something like this. Instead of using the hover effect on
>   the img element, do it on the parent, the $('.imgwall') and then to
>   increase just the image do a $(this).find('img'). and
>   $(this).find('h2').show()/hide() to show the text inside the hover
>   event.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: You should accept your solution as the Answer so this question is resolved. +1 for a good solution, that is also illustrated in this other [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10949913/1195891).

Answer (score 0):

If you prevent hover event while inside the text box, the image reverts to the small size since it's only shown larger while hovering.

Preferably, you should hover over 1 single element, perchance the text-box with very large transparent borders to center it.

If you can, consider using a [jQuery Zoom](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-zoom.html) plugin. Configure the plugin so once your over the image, prior to magnifer the text-box is added.

Comment: is there any way to make it disable the hovering in the text box?

Comment: Not in a way that will retain the larger image because your markup is inside the `.hover()` event. Look at Answer from **Dipaks** on this page for example showing method that reverts to the smaller image once inside the text box.